# Is it possible to do a regex search in Amazon keyspaces?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cassandra, amazon-keyspaces, datastax-node-driver

I am trying to implement seach functionality based on the title field of entries present in amazon keyspaces. I was trying to do a regex match on the title field but I am not to figure out how it could be done. Does amazon keyspace supports regex search? I am using the [Datastax nodeJs driver for cassandra](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/nodejs-driver/4.3/). Also I checked the documentation for amazon keyspace but could not find any useful information.

If anyone is familiar with this, please help me out.

Answer (score 3):

No, as of 20230207, it is not possible to run a regex-based query on Amazon Keyspaces.

Answer (score 0):

That functionality doesn't exist because Cassandra is designed for OLTP workloads where the access pattern is optimised for retrieving one record by filtering on a specific partition key.

Since you have a complex search use case, the general recommendation is to use  search engines based on Lucene such as Elasticsearch or Apache Solr. Both of those are capable of performing complex searches over indexed Cassandra data. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, I wasted a lot of time trying to figure out how to do the regex search on cassandra, but I don't have much experience with elastic search, any blog or something you would recommend?